# Сержант-танкист

Tags: выбор-слов

*Сержант-танкист* или *сержант, танкист?*

Comment: К большинству контекстов (напр. о встреченном военном, давшем интервью) подошло бы "танкист, сержант по званию". "Сержант-танкист" создаёт ложное впечатление, что это формальное воинское звание (ср. "лейтенант-инженер"). "Сержант, танкист" уж очень напоминает название книги "Богач, бедняк".

Comment: А через запятую?

Comment: Выше добавил впечатление об этом.

Comment: Увидела, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

> И при мне раскопали немецкого сержанта. Это мне потом сказали, что он
>   сержант-артиллерист.

Евгений Гришковец. ОдноврЕмЕнно (2004)

Вполне понятная форма, включающая представление о звании и военной специальности.